# Android Image sharing as it is to other app

Tags: android

Can anyone help me how to disable default image editor while image sharing to other apps as whats'app?Send Image as it is picked from folder.

Comment: What is 'default image editor'?

Comment: that means when we try to share image through our application to whatsapp or memegenerator they allow their own editors to edit the image which we want to share.I just want not to open those editors.

Comment: It is unclear what you want. And why you call that default image editors. Don't you want the user to choose whatsapp?

Comment: i want users to choose whatsapp but after choosing whatsapp and selected image which we have to transfer then after selecting the image there is a text to write with the image...I just want not to enable that text writer while image sending.

Comment: Your scenario is difficult to understand as it looks as if the user first selects whatsapp and after that an image. Please tell the right scenario here. It looks as if you want to change the behaviour of whatsapp while sharing an image. I think that is not possible.